# issues deploying modified docker image (custom image ) in google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to deploy a modified docker image on google appengine from the google custom runtimes tutorial but it looks like there are errors that google cloud logs dont seem to show clearly.

Has anyone been able to ever make sense of these logs?

```
Updating service [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/cobalt-door-118421/operations/c34145bb-3baf-4d1b-8e34-e39f0ec65743] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating service [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/cobalt-door-118421/operations/c34145bb-3baf-4d1b-8e34-e39f0ec65743] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating service [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/cobalt-door-118421/operations/c34145bb-3baf-4d1b-8e34-e39f0ec65743] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating service [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/cobalt-door-118421/operations/c34145bb-3baf-4d1b-8e34-e39f0ec65743] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating service [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/myprojectid/operations/c34145bb-3baf-4d1b-8e34-e39f0ec65743] complete. Result: {

Updating service [default]...failed.

DEBUG: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/japheth/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 715, in Execute
    resources = args.calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/home/japheth/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 1538, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/home/japheth/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 80, in Run
    return deploy_util.RunDeploy(self, args, enable_endpoints=True)
  File "/home/japheth/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 378, in RunDeploy
    all_services)
  File "/home/japheth/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 253, in Deploy
    endpoints_info)
  File "/home/japheth/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 118, in DeployService
    return operations.WaitForOperation(self.client.apps_operations, operation)
  File "/home/japheth/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/api/operations.py", line 70, in WaitForOperation
    encoding.MessageToPyValue(completed_operation.error)))
OperationError: Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).
```

@WillHayworth The Dockerfile looks like this

```
   #FROM nginx  
   FROM eu.gcr.io/myprojectid/nginx_september  
   COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf  
   RUN mkdir -p /var/log/app_engine  
   RUN mkdir /usr/local/installations  
   RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah && \  
    echo "healthy" > /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah/health  
   ADD www/ /usr/share/nginx/www/  
   RUN chmod -R a+r /usr/share/nginx/www  This is the example from google,    notice I have FROM pointing to a custom image which is just the original nginx image but modified with say a command like mkdir /usr/local
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about the image you're trying to deploy? What's in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Can you please paste that into your question and format it properly? :)

Comment: @WillHayworth This is the Dockerfile looks like  
#FROM nginx  
FROM eu.gcr.io/myprojectid/nginx_september  
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf  
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/app_engine  
RUN mkdir /usr/local/installations  
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah && \  
    echo "healthy" > /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah/health  
ADD www/ /usr/share/nginx/www/  
RUN chmod -R a+r /usr/share/nginx/www  This is the example from google, notice I have FROM pointing to a custom image which is just the original nginx image but modified with say a command like mkdir /usr/local

Comment: @WillHayworth I am trying to edit this comments, it just exposed my Stackoverflow 'noviseness' , how comes putting two spaces at the end of the line is not generating line breaks?

Comment: That formatting doesn't work in the comments. You need to modify your question.

Comment: Thanks, let me just paste it in the question then

Comment: Thanks @WillHayworth you can see in the Dockerfile there is the line #FROM nginx that is commented out and replaced with  FROM eu.gcr.io/myprojectid/nginx_september   ,  nginx_september is exactly the same image like nginx except that I have created a new directory in its source container then committed and pushed to google repository.

Comment: Okay, but that modified piece is definitely relevant to this. What tutorial are you following?

Comment: @WillHayworth here is the tutorial I am following  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart   The only thing in the modified image is the directory I added into it,  I do intend to make more changes to it but it seems once I have use the new image deployment no longer works.

Comment: Hi @WillHayworth , any chance you got this working? or at least managed to reproduce? Thanks in advance